# PostgreSQL query and shape in json array?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a json array stored in my postgres database in jsonb column. The json data is facebook ad data and look like this:

```
{
"cpc": "1.1",
"cpm": "11.1",
"cpp": "11.1",
"ctr": "0.11",
"ad_id": "11",
"reach": "1",
"spend": "1.1",
"clicks": "11",
"actions": [
    {
        "value": "11",
        "action_type": "video_view"
    },
    {
        "value": "1",
        "action_type": "post_reaction"
    },
    {
        "value": "11",
        "action_type": "mobile_app_install"
    }
],
"ad_name": "ad name here",
"adset_id": "11111",
"date_stop": "2015-05-25",
"frequency": "1.0511",
"adset_name": "adset name here",
"date_start": "2015-05-20",
"campaign_id": "11111111",
"impressions": "1111",
"account_name": "Account name here",
"campaign_name": "campaign_name here",
"unique_clicks": "11",
"unique_actions": [
    {
        "value": "111",
        "action_type": "video_view"
    },
    {
        "value": "11",
        "action_type": "post_reaction"
    },
    {
        "value": "11",
        "action_type": "mobile_app_install"
    },
    {
        "value": "11",
        "action_type": "link_click"
    }
],
"publisher_platform": "instagram",
"inline_link_click_ctr": "0.1111"
```

}

Now, I can select the firt elements like:

```
select jdata->>'cpc' as CPC,
   jdata->>'ad_name' as ad_name,
   jdata->>'cpm' as CPM,
   jdata->>'cpp' as CPP,
   jdata->>'actions' as actions
from my_table_name
```

I want to have row data by selecting and it returns similiar kind that I need. But for **actions** element not. Because **"actions"** element is a json array. I need the "actions" element like json to row but like this format;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| ad_name        |actions->video_view  |actions->mobile_app_install |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| ad name here   |         11          |            1000            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 ad name here |         12          |            10001           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have queried with **jsonb_array_elements** function, but it did not return that i need?

Any help and suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsonb_path_query_first](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function. Here is a sample usage.

> ```
> SELECT
>     jdata->>'ad_name' as ad_name,
>     jsonb_path_query_first(
>       jdata , 
>     '$.actions[*] ? (@.action_type == "video_view").value'
>     ) AS "actions->video_view",
>     jsonb_path_query_first(
>       jdata , 
>     '$.actions[*] ? (@.action_type == "mobile_app_install").value'
>     ) AS "actions->mobile_app_install"
>   FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> ad_name      | actions->video_view | actions->mobile_app_install
> :----------- | :------------------ | :--------------------------
> ad name here | "11"                | "33"
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a50dd6053ac6d8f0276e1a2b3677e172)*

You can read [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) for reference.

Comment: Hi Sahap, thanks for the solution. This works in postgresql version 12.
My postgres db version is 11. and it gives me errors for the **jsonb_path_query_first()** function.